# Why we shouldn't modify the state directly in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) says

For example, this will not re-render a component:

// Wrong

```
this.state.comment = 'Hello';
```

Instead, use setState():

// Correct

```
this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
```

But, there is no answer for the Why? What is the justification for using the second one is correct?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b)

Comment: The justifications are listed in the following chapters in the documentation. State updates in React are asynchronous and immutable, so mutating the state directly with e.g. `this.state.comment = 'Hello';` is prohibited.

Comment: @Tholle I believe he/she is already aware of protocol, but is looking for an explanation as to why, on a fundamental level, `setState` is the correct approach to rerenders. As a technicality, state is not immutable. Rather, it should be treated as immutable to keep references unique when calling `setState`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use such a high level framework, like React, they don't bother explaining to such detail why because it's far too complicated for a simple article. Understanding why would require a deep understanding of React and how the vanilla JavaScript works under the hood. Looking at source code is an option for you, but life is easier when you take their docs at face value.

#### The virtual DOM:

React keeps a copy of the previous state of the page. It uses it as a reference point when it decides on what should be repainted and what shouldn't. When you click on a button, the entire page doesn't need to repaint the entire DOM to values that are completely identical, but what's kind of shitty about JavaScript is the fact that

#### Equality by value does not exist for objects in JavaScript

Finding differences between the virtual DOM and the next DOM that React wants to repaint is impossible because JavaScript has no ability to discern

```js
console.log([] === [])
```

My example doesn't explain the weakness of manually mutating state. It's this one.

```js
this.state = {}
this.state.arr = []
const prevArr = this.state.arr
this.state.arr.push(10)

console.log(this.state.arr === prevArr)
```

An array of `[10]` with a new value is registered as equal to `[]` because equality is done by reference, and adding a value to an existing element is still equal to its previous state. Here is how to fix it. It is no coincidence that you do this in React as well

```js
    this.state = {}
    this.state.arr = []
    const prevArr = [...this.state.arr]
    prevArr.push(10)
    this.state.arr

    console.log(this.state.arr === prevArr)
```

Making a new copy of the array retains all the pointers to the values, but it is its own distinct entity in your hardware's memory. Now they are different. When React traverses its virtual DOM, it now has the ability to register that you inserted `10` into your array and want that to be reflected in the next iteration of the DOM.

#### this.setState triggers a rerender

A rerender is not a complete repainting of the DOM. It is triggering a repaint of the particular element you're passing in when it finds a difference.

Comment: I agree that life is easier while taking docs at face value. I have learned it hard way. But some times, I just cannot blindly take things and look for reason.

Comment: There's a lot to explain before you hit vanilla javascript bedrock. Would you like me to clarify?

Comment: It would definitely help someone on this platform

Comment: @user3705478 Updated

Comment: But if I do `document.getElementByID("thing").innerHTML = "boink"`, then the whole document isn't rerendered either... just the one element with id "thing"... so why is the virtual dom faster?

Comment: @Kokodoko Hmmm, maybe I misspoke or said something misleading. What you did was a manual traversal of the DOM to find that element using `getElementById`. You should think about the scale on which these comparisons are made in a React app and how much can actually change all at once. It basically handles all of that for you.

Comment: Yes I know, but I was just wondering why the virtual dom is faster than manually replacing tags. If you store the reference (`let d = document.getElement...`) you don’t have to traverse the dom each time after a change.

Comment: @Kokodoko You have now asked a question out of my domain of expertise. Apologies, but you'll have to search elsewhere